# Put form fields next to accordion

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

may someone tell me why the form fields don't get displayed on the right of the screen? Even when using `col-6`?

**Code pen:**

https://codepen.io/ogonzales/pen/abjgabQ

**As is:**

[image]

**Expected:**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have forgot to close .col-6 div  on the line number 64:

Please check the below code:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-6">
    <div class="accordion" id="accordionExample">
      <div class="accordion-item">
        <h2 class="accordion-header" id="headingOne">
          <button class="accordion-button" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne"> Requisitos </button>
        </h2>
        <div id="collapseOne" class="accordion-collapse collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-bs-parent="#accordionExample">
          <div class="accordion-body">
            <strong>Ser mayor de 10 años y contar con una computadora (o laptop) y conexión a internet.</strong> Debido a que las clases serán online, el estudiante necesita contar con una computadora para unirse. En su defecto, puede el estudiante podrá unirse desde un dispositivo móvil (celular). <code>.accordion-body</code>, though the transition does limit overflow.
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="accordion-item">
        <h2 class="accordion-header" id="headingTwo">
          <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo"> Características y disctado del curso </button>
        </h2>
        <div id="collapseTwo" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="headingTwo" data-bs-parent="#accordionExample">
          <div class="accordion-body">
            <strong>¿Cómo será el dictado de clases bajo esta modalidad?</strong> Deberás conectarte con tu profesor y compañeros a través de la Plataforma de Videoconferencia Zoom, en el horario y frecuencia de clase que elegiste para el presente ciclo. En esta modalidad, el docente te acompañará siempre en tiempo real, durante los días y horario de clases, facilitando tu aprendizaje. Por ello, ¡El logro de tus metas no se detiene!
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="accordion-item">
        <h2 class="accordion-header" id="headingThree">
          <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree"> Niveles, ciclos y horarios </button>
        </h2>
        <div id="collapseThree" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="headingThree" data-bs-parent="#accordionExample">
          <div class="accordion-body">
            <table class="table">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>a</th>
                  <th>b</th>
                  <th>c</th>
                  <th>d</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td>row 1, column 1</td>
                  <td>row 1, column 2</td>
                  <td>row 1, column 3</td>
                  <td>row 1, column 4</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>row 2, column 1</td>
                  <td>row 2, column 2</td>
                  <td>row 2, column 3</td>
                  <td>row 2, column 4</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>row 3, column 1</td>
                  <td>row 3, column 2</td>
                  <td>row 3, column 3</td>
                  <td>row 3, column 4</td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div> <!-- YOU DID NOT CLOSE THE DIV .col-6 HERE -->
    <div class="col-6">
      <!--=================================
    Contact Us -->
      <section class="space-ptb">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-md-8 text-center">
              <div class="section-title">
                <h2>Get In Touch</h2>
                <p>If success is a process with a number of defined steps, then it is just like any other process. So, what is the first step in any process?</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-9">
              <form class="row fill-form mb-4 mb-md-0 form-flat-style">
                <div class="mb-3 col-sm-6">
                  <label class="form-label">Name</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="">
                </div>
                <div class="mb-3 col-sm-6">
                  <label class="form-label">Email</label>
                  <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="">
                </div>
                <div class="mb-3 col-sm-6">
                  <label class="form-label">Subject</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="">
                </div>
                <div class="mb-3 col-sm-6">
                  <label class="form-label">Phone</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="">
                </div>
                <div class="mb-3 col-sm-12">
                  <label class="form-label">Message</label>
                  <textarea class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlTextarea1" rows="5"></textarea>
                </div>
                <div class="mb-3 col-sm-12">
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Send us</button>
                </div>
              </form>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
              <h4 class="mb-4">Contact Detail</h4>
              <p class="mb-2">6580 Allison Turnpike Creminfort, AL 32808-4509</p>
              <p class="mb-2">
                <b class="text-dark">Call us:</b> +123 4567 8910
              </p>
              <p class="mb-4">
                <b class="text-dark">Mail us:</b> support@online-courses.com
              </p>
              <div class="social-icon-round icon-sm">
                <ul>
                  <li>
                    <a href="#">
                      <i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i>
                    </a>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <a href="#">
                      <i class="fab fa-twitter"></i>
                    </a>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <a href="#">
                      <i class="fab fa-linkedin-in"></i>
                    </a>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <a href="#">
                      <i class="fab fa-instagram"></i>
                    </a>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
      <!--=================================
    Contact Us -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```